# get actual directions from Google Maps Directions API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm generating a map with the route from and to places using the Google Maps Directions API, but how do I get the actual text directions with the javascript API?

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();    
var mapOfDirections;    
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom:6,
    center: center
}
maps = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('main'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(maps);
var request = {
    origin:from,        
    destination:to,
    travelMode:google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status){
if(status==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
});
```

Comment: Set the [panel on the DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
function calculateDirections(){
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsOptions = {
        panel:document.getElementById('directionsDiv')
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(directionsOptions);
    var request = {
        origin:from,    
        destination:to,
        travelMode:google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status){
        if(status==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);        
    });
}
```